# How to clamp rotation in 2D?

Tags: c#

So I'm making a 2D game on unity where you can control gun movement with the mouse. I was wondering how I would go about clamping the movement to you cant keep doing 360's around the player. Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using CodeMonkey.Utils;

public class PlayerAimWeapon : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Transform aimTransform;

    private void Awake()
    {

        aimTransform = gameObject.transform;

    }


    private void Update()
    {
        HandleAiming();
    }

    private void HandleAiming()
    {
        Vector3 mousePosition = UtilsClass.GetMouseWorldPosition();

        Vector3 aimDirection = (mousePosition - transform.position).normalized;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(aimDirection.y, aimDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        aimTransform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, angle);
    }


}
```

Comment: How would you describe (with detailed wording) the behaviours you want to allow and disallow?

Answer (score 1):

```
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(aimDirection.y, aimDirection.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
```

after this try

```
Mathf.Clamp(angle, -180.0f, 180.0f);
```

it will clamp angle to -180 to 180

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html

Comment: I tried implementing the script but nothing happened. The sprite is rotating on the z axis so I think that might be why do you know how to clamp z axis rotation?

Comment: that was for z did you try putting it before this line? aimTransform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, angle); assuming your code was working this should fix your issue